# Selenium stand alone server hang while starting

Tags: selenium

I deployed the selenium standalone server on new digital ocean ubuntu 14.04 server. Its not able to start properly. The log its giving is

```
13:33:57.853 INFO - Launching a standalone server
13:33:57.929 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.25-b02
13:33:57.930 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-37-generic amd64
13:33:57.950 INFO - v2.44.0, with Core v2.44.0. Built from revision 76d78cf
13:33:58.060 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match with current platform: LINUX
13:33:58.191 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
13:33:58.196 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
13:33:58.199 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
```

I guess 2 lines are missing in the log it.

```
14:54:06.454 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
14:54:06.462 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@b1bc7ed
```

Does anybody have any idea why its happening??

Comment: Having the same issue. Selenium starts instantly on EC2 and my laptop, but take 5+ minutes and sometimes hours to start on DigitalOcean. I am using selenium inside Docker, so all configuration and environment is identical. I also tried two different selenium docker images — both are affected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It happens when selenium tries to generate a random seed, but the kernel lacks entropy.

The solution is to install software that adds entropy like `haveged`. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged

Comment: I've found that this applies especially to Digital Ocean droplets

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on RHEL 7... was entropy as well

To check whether you have the same issue :

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`

shows a really low number... (I had 3)

To get it working :

`yum install rng-tools
systemctl enable rngd.service
systemctl start rngd.service`

Afterwards the number rose to 3000 and the selenium server came up...

Comment: Using rng-tools and raising the entropy solved this for me. I was running into this problem on a RHEL7 OS outside of digital ocean.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me due to a port collision. If some other process is running on 4444, Selenium wont start, and Nightwatch doesnt tell you the error.

Changing, the port to 4445, in nightwatch.json, fixed it for me: 

`"selenium" : {
     ...
    "port" : 4445,`