# Selenium node Digital Ocean through ssh Xvfb - does not attempt to connect to hub

Tags: selenium, ssh, selenium-grid, digital-ocean

Trying to run selenium node on headless Digital Ocean machine through ssh with xvfb on Ubuntu 14. All packages installed, chromium-browser launches correctly on xvfb.

It behaves strangely: no error, but does not attempt to connect hub at all. Instead starts Jetty only.

Exact command line:

```
xvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0 1920x1280x24" java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role node -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -hub "http://localhost:4444/grid/register" -browser "browserName=chrome, platform=LINUX, maxInstances=5, chrome.binary=/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
```

On my local PC the node attempts connection to hub, while on headless Digital Ocean nothing happens and hub does not list the node on the /grid/console page. **The only clue is that the last lines of node logs differ.**

Headless Digital Ocean:

```
11:55:53.483 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
11:55:53.484 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
```

My PC:

```
17:52:04.859 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
17:52:04.877 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
17:52:04.877 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://46.101.128.117:4444/grid/register
17:52:04.936 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

**Any ideas what might be wrong? Had anyone succeeded with similar setup?**

---

*Full logs at Digital Ocean headless:*

```
11:55:52.753 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
11:55:52.820 INFO - Adding browserName=chrome, platform=LINUX, maxInstances=5, chrome.binary=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to ./chromedriver
11:55:53.347 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02
11:55:53.348 INFO - OS: Linux 3.19.0-22-generic amd64
11:55:53.354 INFO - v2.48.0, with Core v2.48.0. Built from revision 41bccdd
11:55:53.433 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
11:55:53.434 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
11:55:53.434 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
11:55:53.435 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
11:55:53.483 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
11:55:53.484 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
```

*The same example run on my PC gives:*

```
17:52:04.341 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
17:52:04.387 INFO - Adding browserName=chrome, platform=LINUX, maxInstances=5, chrome.binary=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to ./chromedriver
17:52:04.750 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02
17:52:04.750 INFO - OS: Linux 3.19.0-30-generic amd64
17:52:04.754 INFO - v2.48.0, with Core v2.48.0. Built from revision 41bccdd
17:52:04.816 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
17:52:04.817 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
17:52:04.818 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
17:52:04.818 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
17:52:04.859 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
17:52:04.877 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
17:52:04.877 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://46.101.128.117:4444/grid/register
17:52:04.936 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running selenium node on Linux in a virtual machine or headless server (including Digital Ocean VMs), you will probably have this problem. This is because your VM/server does not have enough entropy available.

To resolve this problem, simply install `haveged` (or other similar things).

To install it on CentOS 7, you need have EPEL enabled, then run:

```
yum install haveged
systemctl enable haveged
systemctl start haveged
```

For other Linux distributions, see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged

Answer (score 1):

**I have the solution.**

It is already described in [Selenium stand alone server hang while starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216816/selenium-stand-alone-server-hang-while-starting).

Root cause: Digital Ocean machines have some weak entropy, so need to use additional software tool.

Would be nice if selenium detects that and displays some message instead of hanging.

Comment: Following the article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216816/selenium-stand-alone-server-hang-while-starting fixed this for me. I was on a RHEL7 machine outside of digital ocean facing similar issues.